# Change URL of Alert in Document Library - SharePoint 2013

Tags: alert, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a document library named `Sample` in SharePoint 2013.

The internal site collection URL is like `http://wonderland/` and its public URL is `https://access.wonderland.com`.

I have created an Alert for this document library. Whenever anything changes, it sends email alert to the user.

The URL for the `Sample` library item sent by alert is like `http://wonderland/Sample`. But I want to change it to external URL which will be like `https://access.wonderland.com/Sample`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ryan. I have tried this option but did not work for me unfortunately. However I found my own solution. All I have to do is configure some Alternate Access Mapping settings as described in this blog.

http://sharepointrealm.blogspot.com/2013/05/change-url-of-emails-send-in-document.html

Merin

Answer (score 0):

This worked in 2007 and 2010 - haven't tried it but I would expect it to work.

```
stsadm -o updatealert -url http://yournewurl -oldurl http://yournewurl
```

See http://sharepointalert.info/2009/10/troubleshooting-url-alert-email-incorrect/